# Adding class to element using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I know how to add a class on click of a button in 'jQuery'

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
 $('#div1').addClass('alpha');
});
```

I want to achieve same thing by angular js. I have a controller - myController1. Can someone help me do it eazily?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

AngularJS has some methods called JQlite so we can use it. see [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Select the element in DOM is

```
angular.element( document.querySelector( '#div1' ) );
```

add the class like `.addClass('alpha');`

So finally

```
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#div1' ) );
myEl.addClass('alpha');
```

Answer (score 35):

You can use `ng-class` to add conditional classes.

HTML

```
<button id="button1" ng-click="alpha = true" ng-class="{alpha: alpha}">Button</button>
```

In your controller (to make sure the class is not shown by default)

```
$scope.alpha = false;
```

Now, when you click the button, the $scope.alpha variable is updated and ng-class will add the 'alpha' class to your button.

Comment: Didn't work until I added ' ' around the class (first alpha). Also why make the boolean variable same name as the class, could be confusing to some people. Downvote

Answer (score 25):

### Use the MV* Pattern

Based on the example you attached, 
**It's better in angular to use the following tools:**

- **`ng-click`** - evaluates the expression when the element is clicked ([**Read More**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick))
- **`ng-class`** - place a class based on the a given boolean expression ([**Read More**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass))

**for example:**

```
<button ng-click="enabled=true">Click Me!</button>

<div ng-class="{'alpha':enabled}"> 
    ...
</div>
```

This gives you an easy way to decouple your implementation.
e.g. you don't have any dependency between the `div` and the `button`.

**[Read this to learn about the MV* Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20286917/3191896)**

Comment: Yeah, It's the pure angular way. No jQuery needed :D

Answer (score 5):

Try this..

If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.click=function(){

      angular.element('#div1').addClass("alpha");
    };
});
<div id='div1'>Text</div>
<button ng-click="click()">action</button>
```

Ref:https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score 5):

First thing, you should not do any DOM manipulation in controller function.
Instead, you should use directives for this purpose. directive's link function is available for those kind of stuff only.

**[AngularJS Docs : Creating a Directive that Manipulates the DOM](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom)**

```
app.directive('buttonDirective', function($timeout) {
  return {
    scope: {
       change: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          // triggering callback
          scope.change();
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

change callback can be used as listener for click event.

Answer (score 2):

`querySelector` is not from Angular but it's in `document` and it's in all DOM elements (expensive). You can use `ng-class` or inside directive add `addClass` on the element:

```
myApp.directive('yourDirective', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            // Remove class
            elem.addClass("my-class"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Angular 7 users:**

Here I show you that you can activate or deactivate a simple class attribute named "blurred" with just a boolean. Therefore u need to use `[ngClass]`.

**TS class**

```
blurredStatus = true
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="inner-wrapper" [ngClass]="{'blurred':blurredStatus}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**In HTML**

To add the class named ***alpha***, assign any variable like ***showAlpha*** to false first and then set it to true on click.

```
<div data-ng-class="{'alpha' : showAlpha}"> </div>

<button ng-click="addClass()"> </button>
```

**In JS file**

```
$scope.showAlpha = false;

$scope.addClass = function(){
   $scope.showAlpha = true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
<script>
       angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("#div1")).addClass("alpha");
</script>
```

[click the link and understand more](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#overview)

**Note**: Keep in mind that **angular.element()**  function will not find directly select any documnet location using this perameters 
**angular.element(document).find(...)** or **$document.find()**, or use the standard DOM APIs, **e.g. document.querySelectorAll()**

Comment: Why? Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: Note: Keep in mind that this function will not find elements by tag name / CSS selector. For lookups by tag name, try instead angular.element(document).find(...) or $document.find(), or use the standard DOM APIs, e.g. document.querySelectorAll().

Comment: Please do not copy&paste content from other sites without proper attribution. Rather explain the code you've written, and why that solves the problem

Comment: not a copy this code this create me and refer a angular js officeal site

Comment: You created that last line (starting with "Note") and contributed it to the AngularJS documentation? Ok, didn't know that. But then you should be able to explain further how exactly your code solves the problem - just have a look at the other answers that contain nearly the same code