# setting jquery validator errorClass manually

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using Jquery validator on a simple email input form.

```
<form name="form" submit.delegate="submit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ea">Email</label>
        <input type="email" value.bind="emailaddy" class="form-control" id="ea" name="ea" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit" id="submitbutton"class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My validator rules are handling the required and valid email and my custom error messages show up correctly.  On submit I want to check if the email already exists. The webApi call works but I don't know how to set the Jquery validator errorClass on my emailaddy element.

```
submit() {
    var vm  = this; 

    return vm.webApi.emailExists(vm.emailaddy)
        .then(function (data) {

            if (data === true) {
                console.log("email exists, don't submit");
                // set errorClass for the email element
            }
            else {
                console.log("email not found, submit");
                // do the submit
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Your code looks like AngularJS.  If so, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410402/adding-class-to-element-using-angular-js

Comment: it's plain Javascript, the question is only about setting the error class and validation state with Jquery validator.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking for.  If you just want to add a class with JS:  `document.getElementById("ea").setAttribute("class", "errorClass");`  With jQuery it's:  `$("#ea").addClass("errorClass");`