# How to use add class property in angular2

Tags: jquery, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have issue for my angularjs 2 code.I want to apply this css through angular2.

Here, my jquery code :

[image: Jquery code]

Show how can I use this code in angular 2. how should I use the property add class in angular 2.

Please help me.

Comment: do you even try to google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410402/adding-class-to-element-using-angular-js

Comment: yes, but I think that not work for angular 2. I am searching for angular 2 not angularjs

Comment: you think or you tried and sure it doesn't work?

Comment: I tried but isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunate that everyone so far is giving you Angular answers..  When using Angular2, try not to use jQuery.  There are very few cases where jQuery should be used directly.

To conditionally add a class to a DOM element, you need to add a conditional variable to the element itself.

For example, if you want `<input id="username" class="username">` to conditionally have the `slide1` class, you would change the input element to look like this:

`<input id="username" class="username [class.slide1]="myBoolean">`

That boolean value can be set by the click function.  To add a click event to, say, a button, you would have `<input type="button" (click)="myFunction()">`.  You would then define a function called myFunction() in the component.  `myFunction()` would set `this.myBoolean` to true or false, which will toggle the slide1 class.

See [here for how events (like click) in angular2 work](http://learnangular2.com/events/) and [here for conditionally adding styles](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/01/learning-ng2-dynamic-styles/).

Comment: Agreed, you should not be using jQuery in Angular2.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 app.controller('showCrtl',function($scope){
   $scope.addclass=function(event){
        event.target.classList.add('colorClass');
      };
 });
```

```css
.colorClass{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="showCrtl">
  <input type="button" value="click" ng-click=addclass($event)>
</div>
```

Please check the code hope will help you out

thanks

Comment: Thanks for reply but, I am searching for angular 2