# Add styles to a existing class with angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have many existing classes in my app and want to set the style via code (theming feature).

e.g. `<button class="mybutton">click</button>`

I need something like:

```
<style>
    .mybutton{
        background-color: {{company?.buttonBackgroundColor}}!important;
    }
</style>
```

but of course this doesn't work. What would be a nice solution without replacing all existing classes?

EDIT: Angular 2+, not angular js. sorry

Comment: Why not use css vars for that? you can set there value through JS.

Comment: not supported in ie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me a good solution was vanilla js:

```
var selects = document.getElementsByClassName('mybutton')
        for (var i = 0, il = selects.length; i < il; i++) {
            selects[i].style.color = this.company.buttonForegroundColor;

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a different approach for theming. Create a *.css file overriding necessary rules for each theme and dynamically add apropriate stylesheet to DOM when you want to switch theme (take a look at [How to load up CSS files using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript) to find out how to do that).

Answer (score 0):

In angular, you can just access the element and change it's class. You can do way more things, like change it's properties too, but I think that working with classes is neater.
Then, you use add classes to the DOM using:

```
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#div1' ) );
myEl.addClass('alpha');
```

Here you can find some ideas for it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30410490/5250103

Also, another good solution would be using conditional classes (ngClass):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16529903/5250103

There he explains:

> The ngClass directive will work with any expression that evaluates truthy or falsey, a bit similar to Javascript expressions but with some differences, you can read about [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). If your conditional is too complex, then you can use a function that returns truthy or falsey, as you did in your third attempt.

An example given [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/j4r8MDt3Q77NFJlhv7oQ?p=preview)

```
ng-class="{'test': obj.value1 == 'someothervalue' || obj.value2 == 'somethingelse'}"
```

I don't intend to steal any anwser, but as suggested in comments, this was edited and it is quoting it's authors.

I hope it helps!