# Using Ui-Router and adhering to good design patterns

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Learning Angular. Working with 1.6.6.

Trying to use `ui.router`, running into an issue with injecting components.

I've been using the following as resources to structure my project:
[AngularJS: Understanding design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286917/angularjs-understanding-design-pattern)
https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app

Both these resources suggest using `module` as a container for the code underneath them. For example from my own project:

```
angular.
    module('randomTownGenerator.module', [
        'randomTown.service',
        'randomTown.controller'
    ]);
```

Each of those dependancies is defined in its own file. When I specify the above `module` as the component for the the route:

```
var randomTownGenerator = {
            name: 'randomTownGenerator',
            url: '/random-town',
            component: 'randomTownGenerator.module'
        }
```

I get:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: randomTownGenerator.moduleDirectiveProvider <- randomTownGenerator.moduleDirective
```

How can I pass the `randomTownGenerator.module`, which is just a wrapper around the `service`, `template`, and `controller`, to `ui.router`?

Comment: Learning Angular 1.x can be waste of time for you. Angular's version is 5 nowadays and Angular totally changed  after version 1.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have provided a module where it is expecting an angular component.

> component: 'randomTownGenerator.module'

Here angular-ui-router is expecting a angular component to generate as the view for the state 'randomTownGenerator'. Please refer the angularjs documentation on how to create a component.
https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/docs/guide/component

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to mixup the angularjs earlier version of injecting a module and new way of injecting module.

You should provide a component as a view with the later version so that will be loaded when it is required.

```
 var States = {
        "app": {
            path: "",
            routing: null,
            definition: {
                name: "app",
                url: "",
                onEnter: function () {

                    console.info("App state entered.");
                },
                params: {
                    //
                },
                resolve: {
                    //
                },
                views: {
                    "app@": {
                        component: "appComponent"
                    }
                },
                abstract: true
            }
        }
    };
```

where component should be a component not a module. Here is a **[`complete example`](https://github.com/sajeetharan/angular-uirouter-demo)** of how to create states with ui-router and angularjs 1.6 version