# In Angular, how do I reach in to possibly deep child scopes to change things like validity?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a simple form that looks like this:

```
<form name="myForm">
  <input name="field" ng-model="item.field"></input>
  <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
</form>
```

In theory, I should be able to change things like validity of fields in the controller based on the form and field, as such:

```
$scope.save = function(item) {
  item.$save();
  $scope.myForm.field.$setValidity("some-error",false);
};
```

The problem is that directives at various levels get in the way and may set up multiple child scopes. So while `item.field` is properly rendered and linked, my ability to do anything from the controller is very limited, e.g. if I wrap my partial in a fancy "loading" directive that hides it and shows "loading" until done.

```
<loading>
  <form name="myForm">
    <input name="field" ng-model="item.field"></input>
    <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
  </form>
</loading>
```

Now my controller that wanted to directly set validity no longer has access to `$scope.myForm`. Truth is, with possible directives, it *never* can safely rely on access to `$scope.myForm`; only a directive can!

@Beyers recommends passing the form as part of the `save()` call, as `<button ng-click="save(myForm)">Save</button>`, which definitely works, but gets cumbersome.

Is there a real Angular way to do this cleanly? Should I be resetting to `$pristine` inside my controller directly, or is there some other thing to do?

UPDATE:

I am beginning to wonder if this is the right approach at all. Should my controller be doing this like `$setValidity` on a form? Shouldn't it take input from the view and modify business objects (`item`) on that basis, as well as interact with services? How does angular know to reset `ng-dirty` or `ng-invalid` for its own validations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that directives at various levels get in the way and may set up multiple child scopes.

You're hitting the standard [if you don't have a dot in your model, you're doing it wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/angularjs-if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong) issue. This isn't just true for ng-model, but also for form name.

A solution is to make sure you have an object in your controller for forms, such as `forms`:

```
$scope.forms = {};
```

In the template use `forms.<formName>`:

```
<form name="forms.myForm">
  ...
</form>
```

And then in the controller code to access the form, use `$scope.forms.<formName>`

```
$scope.forms.myForm.field.$setValidity("some-error" ,false);
```

And your updated question:

> Should my controller be doing this like $setValidity on a form

I would address this on a case-by-case basis in order to KISS. Validity is often the result of interacting with services, and can be related to business objects/rules. A little bit of code in the controller interacting with validation I would say is ok, but if your controller is getting a bit long with a quite a few responsibilities, then it might then be a good idea to try to move some of the logic into custom directives on the elements that require `ngModel`. These can then accept parameters/functions via attributes, set by the controller, if required.

Comment: @MichaelCharemza, thanks for the detailed response. I know the "dot in your model" problem, but did *not* know that it applied to form name as well. And you are saying that whatever directives are getting in the way can be bypassed the same way as ng-model is applied to the various elements? I will have to try that solution, thank you.

Comment: I do find that I am doing too much in the directive here. Imagine a simple page that displays info, but when you click "Edit" switches them all to input fields so you can edit them, and converts the "Edit" button to a "Save" and "Cancel". I will add a jsfiddle below. How would I properly do this in a directive? By the by, this edit/save/cancel process occurs in multiple controllers, almost identical.

Comment: @deitch It sounds like this is leading towards a different question to your original one. If so, I think post as a new question.

Comment: Heh, actually it grew out of a different one, I was trying to isolate the problem so the SO question would be very narrowly defined (and thus easier to answer). I hate dumping "this is big and doesn't work" questions on here; I far prefer to isolate the 2-3 particular issues and ask them. :-)

Comment: In any case, I will post a separate question and include the fiddle on it there

Comment: Here's the fiddle, will open a separate question with it. http://jsfiddle.net/shp0e10q/1/

Comment: And the new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974097/how-to-isolate-async-validity-checks-from-controller-to-directive-to-solve-dry-a

Comment: Either way, this specific question is correctly answered, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just grabbed the form field by Id last time I did this and it worked fine.
Using the ID, you "Angularize" it and then you can access it's model etc...

Like this:

```
//you will need to add an id to your field.
var myInput = angular.element(document.querySelector('#myInput'));
var ngModelCtrl = myInput.controller('ngModel');

ngModelCtrl.$setValidity("some-error",false);
```

The angular docs say that you should only do this when you have to, they prefer you to use the `ngModel.$validators` pipline. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to use that myself so can't help you there.

Comment: I didn't think of doing that, but it can get messy quickly. It feels very old-style jquery-ish. I feel like I am going about this all wrong, that I should be setting the model(s) state in the controller, and the view should adjust itself (including pristine-state) based on tis validity. But not sure how.