# $scope variable does not update within $interval function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using `$interval` for my custom stopwatch. Within the `$interval` function I have a variable `$scope.inputValue` which is binded to a range. The problem is that after each iteration of `$interval` (every 500ms), the most recent $scope.inputValue is not taken into account, but only the value at the initialization (1000).

How to solve this?

**Controller**

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {

    var interval, incrementTimer;

    $scope.inputValue       = 1000;

    //
    //
    incrementTimer = function() {
        userValue = $scope.inputValue; 
        console.log(userValue); // does not update when range changes
    };


    //
    // button toggle
    $scope.toggleTimer = function() {
        interval = $interval(incrementTimer, 500);
    };

})
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="2000" step="100" ng-model="inputValue">

<button class="button button-positive" ng-click="toggleTimer()">Start</button>
```

Comment: Where are you calling `$scope.toggleTimer()`?

Comment: @devqon in my html, on a button click (I have updated the question).

Comment: try logging  $scope.inputValue inside of incrementTimer, do you get the correct result?

Comment: @ajmajmajma no, it just stays the same value (1000), despite me changing the range (even when I change it before I initiate toggleTimer())

Comment: Any other console errors?

Comment: @JohnAndrews could you make a fiddle or something? would be easier to debug if it we could see it running in something. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is probably [not using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model) a [dot in `ng-model`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/angularjs-if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong). If it is the case, then there may be an inherited scope being created by a parent node which contains the HTML you posted. Posting some more context around it will help in debugging it.

Comment: This code works 100% for me in jsfiddle. Check console errors. Ajs version....

Comment: @musically_ut that was indeed the problem... do you want to anser this question so I can accept it or do you prefer that I answer it on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably not using a dot in `ng-model`. There probably is an inherited scope being created by a parent node which contains the HTML posted in the question.

See also:

- [Why don't the AngularJS docs use a dot in the model directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/angularjs-dot-in-ng-model)
- [If you are not using a .(dot) in your AngularJS models you are doing it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/angularjs-if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was probably about the dot thingy you all spoke about.
However, I needed to remove announcement on the controller:

```
<ion-view view title="bla bla" ng-controller="tabletStayInTouchCtrl" on-touch="onTouch()">
```

Had to be changed to this:

```
<ion-view view title="bla bla"  on-touch="onTouch()">
```

I guess it is all about the parental-controller that caused the problem.