# Two way databinding does not work in <ion-content>

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, ionic-framework

Two way databinding is not woking in `<ion-content>`. I am not able to get updated value of $scope variable ("searchKeyword" in this case). If i put the html outside the `<ion-conent>` then it works. I am very confused about this behavior.Below code works,

```
<ion-view view-title="Search" >
  <div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset" style="height:52px;">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchKeyword" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? search() : null">
    </label>
    <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="search()">
      search
    </button>
  </div>
  <ion-content scroll="true" style="margin-top:50px;" >

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

but below does not :(

```
 <ion-view view-title="Search" >

      <ion-content scroll="true" style="margin-top:50px;" >
    <div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset" style="height:52px;">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
          <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchKeyword" ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? search() : null">
        </label>
        <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="search()">
          search
        </button>
      </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

Here, on search() function i don't get updated value of "searchKeyword". Below is my controller,

```
angular.module('myapp')
.controller('SearchController',function($scope){
$scope.searchKeyword='';
  $scope.search=function(){
    console.log('search keyword : '+$scope.searchKeyword);
  };
})
```

Comment: This could be because somewhere along the way, within your scope hierarchy, a child scope was created.  Then when it's assigned, it creates a copy of the variable in child scope that is a copy of the variable in parent scope - two way binding broken. Try adding a "dot" in your ngModel. I.e. $scope.my.searchKeyword

Comment: Initialize in your controller $scope.my = { searchKeyword:'' };

Comment: Please share your example on http://codepen.io

Comment: Here is the download link.You will get example here, [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwZLxaWkixXbNkxrMU8tQUxvSU0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @pixelbits the method u told me is working (y) Thanks, but i don't understand why it is not working in regular way. I have read the case you have put in comment but i have only one controller at this point.

Answer (score 2):

`$scope.searchKeyword` in `search()` and `ng-model` refer to different scopes after the value of input has changed, because `<ion-content>` creates new scope. Unfortunately, for primitive values, this needs to be worked around. Please see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18128502/3603869) for deeper explanation.