# $watch is not calling inside tabs in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-watch

Here's [**my example on Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EhRHkJZZyczMKI00A5aJ?p=preview)

```
Hi All,
```

In my example, I created two input text boxes, one is outside the tab another one is inside. For both I created a watch function. The outside one is working fine, but the watch function inside the tab is not working. Both places have same type of coding, only I don't know why one is working and the other isn't.

Can anyone help me on this?

```js
angular.module('components', []).
  directive('tabs', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {},
      controller: [ "$scope", function($scope) {
        var panes = $scope.panes = [];
 
        $scope.select = function(pane) {
          angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
            pane.selected = false;
          });
          pane.selected = true;
        }
 
        this.addPane = function(pane) {
          if (panes.length == 0) $scope.select(pane);
          panes.push(pane);
        }
      }],
      template:
        '<div class="tabbable">' +
          '<ul class="nav nav-tabs">' +
            '<li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">'+
              '<a href="" ng-click="select(pane)">{{pane.title}}</a>' +
            '</li>' +
          '</ul>' +
          '<div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>',
      replace: true
    };
  }).
  directive('pane', function() {
    return {
      require: '^tabs',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: { title: '@' },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
        tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
      },
      template:
        '<div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{active: selected}" ng-transclude>' +
        '</div>',
      replace: true
    };
  })
  .controller('sample', function($scope){
    $scope.cancel = function(){
      console.log("cancel")
    }
    $scope.$watch('FirstName', function() {
  console.log("FirstName")
    //  fetch();
    });
    $scope.$watch('FirstName1', function() {
  console.log("FirstName1")
    //  fetch();
    });
      //Here I need to Change Selected Tab
  })
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

 
    
 
  </head>

  <body ng-app="components" ng-controller="sample">
  <h3>BootStrap Tab Component</h3>
  <form role="form" ng-controller="sample">
     <input type="text"  ng-model="FirstName1" class="form-control" id="FirstName1">
  <tabs>
    <pane id="FirstTab" title="First Tab">
      <div><div class="form-group">
    <label for="text">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" required ng-model="FirstName" class="form-control" id="FirstName">
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="text">Middle Name</label>
    <input type="text" required ng-model="MiddleName" class="form-control" id="MiddleName">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="text">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" required ng-model="LastName" class="form-control" id="LastName">
  </div>
  
  </div>
    </pane>
    <pane id="SecondTab" title="Second Tab">
      <div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="text">Contact</label>
          <input type="text" required ng-model="Contact" class="form-control" id="Contact">
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="text">Address1</label>
          <input type="text" required ng-model="Address1" class="form-control" id="Address1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="text">Address2</label>
          <input type="text" required ng-model="Address2" class="form-control" id="Address2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </pane>
     <pane id="ThirdTab" title="Third Tab">
      <div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="text">Phone</label>
          <input type="text" required ng-model="Phone" class="form-control" id="Phone">
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="text">Mobile</label>
          <input type="text" required ng-model="Mobile" class="form-control" id="Mobile">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="text">Mobile1</label>
          <input type="text" required ng-model="Mobile1" class="form-control" id="Mobile1">
        </div>
      </div>
    </pane>
     <pane id="FourthTab" title="Fourth Tab">
      <div>This is the content of the Fourth tab.</div>
    </pane>
  </tabs>
    <button type="submit" ng-click="Submit()" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you put the code in your question? Because I'm not going to click some random link while at work, plus if it's not enough code to fit here nicely then you need to narrow down the source of the problem first.

Comment: $scope.$watch('FirstName', function() {
  console.log("FirstName")
    });
    $scope.$watch('FirstName1', function() {
  console.log("FirstName1")
    });

Comment: Inside ng-model='FirstName' outside ng-model='FirstName1'

Comment: @ Marty  I added Codes Here Itself can you check and let me know where I did mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use dot in ng-model. Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/angularjs-if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong)

So your code will work if same as:

At javascipt file

```
.controller('sample', function($scope){
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.cancel = function(){
      console.log("cancel")
    }
    $scope.$watch('user.FirstName', function() {
        console.log("FirstName")
    //  fetch();
    });
    $scope.$watch('FirstName1', function() {
        console.log("FirstName1")
    //  fetch();
    });
      //Here I need to Change Selected Tab
  })
```

At Html file:

```
<pane id="FirstTab" title="First Tab">
    <div><div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" required ng-model="user.FirstName" class="form-control" id="FirstName">
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Middle Name</label>
            <input type="text" required ng-model="user.MiddleName" class="form-control" id="MiddleName">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" required ng-model="user.LastName" class="form-control" id="LastName">
        </div>

    </div>
</pane>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a different way .. using ng-change too .. It watches for any change in the model and calls the function accordingly. Add this instead of the $watch.

```
 $scope.change = function() {
  console.log("FirstName")
}
```

In the template call the ng-change as follows

```
    <input type="text" required ng-model="FirstName" ng-change="change()" class="form-control" id="FirstName">
```

Here's the link to the edited plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sthlx4i467naXZAa09LU?p=preview)