# Best practice of using $scope.$apply(); or even $scope in non-Angular stuff with Angular Component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

According to [Kendo best practices](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/a-few-angular-kendo-ui-best-practices), Kendo sometimes requires to use `$scope.$apply();` to update Angular. Howerver, ***new AngularJS 1.5 component*** discourages to use `$scope`.

***Old Controller*** - http://dojo.telerik.com/exok

***New 1.5 Component*** - http://plnkr.co/edit/tPTqlzlC9Obn5UFRUqc2?p=preview

In order to make the above code to work, I gotta assign ***this*** to a variable. *For example,* `var self = this; ... self.firstName = item.firstName;.`

***My Question*** is how we apply Angular correctly without using `$scope.$apply();` or even `$scope` when we are dealing with Kendo or even non-Angular stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your way to creating 'self' variable is correct. Because if you use '`this`', it will refer to the object/context executing the `change` method, not the controller.
See updated version at http://plnkr.co/edit/AbVz2IqY0b6tT5pds2rF?p=preview

`$scope.$apply()` is used to trigger Angular `$digest` cycle.

Normally you don't have to call it manually because Angular framework is already doing it for you at some different level of code.
For example, you can see the [source code of `ng-click` directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L69), Angular call `$apply` by itself.

In your example, Kendo UI Grid requires you to call `$apply` directly because the `gridOption.change` callback is executed by Kendo UI Grid, not by Angular. So you must call `$apply` to tell Angular to run `$digest` cycle to check for any dirty values and update the views accordingly.

Regarding the best practice, since 1.3, Angular introduced `controller as` syntax, which helped enforce the ['dot notation'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/angularjs-if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong) best practice and further eliminate the use of 'scope'. In 1.5, they continue eliminating the verbosity of 'directive' usage by introducing 'component' usage. 
All of these are part of the transition steps to ease the  migrating from Angular 1.x to Angular 2. Check out [the official guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html) to see more about the recommended steps.