# angular simple binding not working in controller

Tags: angularjs

I have done this before. It has always work. For some reason, it is not working anymore.

I have the following two inputs..

```
 <input id="input1" ng-model="searchString2" />

 <input ng-model="searchString2" ng-keypress="($event.which === 13)?searchPatient():0" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
```

In my controller :

```
$scope.searchString2 = "test";

$scope.searchPatient = function () {
            $scope.response = null;
            alert($scope.searchString2);

            var url = baseUrl + 'api/patient?etag=' + $scope.etag.value + '&searchString=' + $scope.searchString2;

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url

            }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                $scope.response = response.data;


            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                $scope.errorMessage = response.statusText;
            });
        };
```

When I type into any of two inputs, the other input is updated as expected.
However, I call the searchPatient function, the $scope.searchString2 is always equal to its initial value ("test").

Any idea why?

**UPDATE**

This is how I set the controller:

```
angular
    .module('myApp',
    [
        'ngRoute',
        'myApp.ctrl.home',
        'myApp.ctrl.etag',
        'myApp.ctrl.about',
        'myApp.ctrl.partner'
    ])
    .config([
        '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

            var baseUrl = $("base").first().attr("href");
            //console.log("base url for relative links = " + baseUrl);

            // Specify the three simple routes ('/', '/About', and '/Contact')
            $routeProvider.when('/',
            {
                templateUrl: baseUrl + '/Home/Home',
                controller: 'partnerCtrl',
                activetab: 'home'
            });
            $routeProvider.when('/Priorx',
            {
                templateUrl: baseUrl + '/Home/About',
                controller: 'aboutCtrl',
                activetab: 'priorx'
            });

            $routeProvider.otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });

            // Specify HTML5 mode (using the History APIs) or HashBang syntax.
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');

        }
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
angular
    .module("myApp.ctrl.about", ["ngCookies"])
    .controller("aboutCtrl", ["$scope", "$sce", "$http", "$window", "$cookies", function ($scope, $sce, $http, $window, $cookies) {

        var w = angular.element($window);
        var iframe = angular.element(document.querySelector('#iFrame'));

        $scope.version = "1.0.0";
        $scope.windowWidth = 0;
        $scope.windowHeight = 0;

        var setDimensions = function () {
            $scope.windowWidth = w.width();
            $scope.windowHeight = w.height();
        };

        w.bind('resize', function () {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                setDimensions();
            });
        });
        setDimensions();

        var baseUrl = $("base").first().attr("href"),
            _login = function (username, password) {
                //$http.post(baseUrl + 'api/login', { 'username': username, 'password': password })
                //    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //        if (data === "")
                //            $scope.errorMessage = "Login failed.";
                //        else {
                //            $scope.etag = {
                //                value: data,
                //                expiration: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
                //            };
                //            setEtag($scope.etag);
                //        }

                //    })
                //    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                //        if (data.exceptionMessage)
                //            $scope.errorMessage = data.exceptionMessage;
                //        else {
                //            $scope.errorMessage = "An error has occured!";
                //        }
                //    });



                $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: baseUrl + 'api/login',
                    data: { username: username, password: password }
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    var data = response.data;
                    if (data === "")
                        $scope.errorMessage = "Login failed!";
                    else {
                        $scope.etag = {
                            value: data,
                            expiration: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
                        };
                        setEtag($scope.etag);
                    }
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    $scope.errorMessage = response.statusText;
                });

            },

            _logoff = function (etag) {
                $http.post(baseUrl + 'api/logout',
                        "=" + etag,
                        {
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                            }
                        })
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        if (data === true) {
                            clearEtag();
                        } else {
                            $scope.errorMessage = "failed to logoff";
                        }
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(data);
                        if (data.exceptionMessage)
                            $scope.errorMessage = data.exceptionMessage;
                        else {
                            $scope.errorMessage = "An error has occured!";
                        }
                    });
            },

            setEtag = function (etag) {
                console.log('etag', etag);
                $cookies.putObject('etag', etag);
            },

            clearEtag = function () {
                $cookies.remove('etag');
                $scope.etag = null;
            },

            getEtag = function () {
                var e = $cookies.getObject('etag');


                if (e && e.value && e.value.length > 0) {

                    if (new Date() < new Date(e.expiration))
                        $scope.etag = e;
                    else {
                        $scope.warningMessage = "Cached ETAG was removed because it has expired!";
                        clearEtag();
                    }
                } else $scope.etag = null;
            };

        $scope.errorMessage = "";
        $scope.warningMessage = "";
        $scope.username = "PJT";
        $scope.password = "benoit";
        $scope.etag = null;
        $scope.loading = false;
        $scope.infoMessagePatient = "";
        $scope.errorMessagePatient = "";
        $scope.patient = {};
        $scope.response = null;
        $scope.searchString2 = "";
        $scope.appUrl = "http://noranda.pfsserver.com/inr/index.html?lang=fr#/";
        $scope.srciFrame = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.appUrl);
        $scope.url = $scope.appUrl;

        // functions


        $scope.connect = function () {
            $scope.errorMessage = "";
            _login($scope.username, $scope.password);
        };

        $scope.logout = function () {
            $scope.errorMessage = "";
            _logoff($scope.etag.value);
        };


        $scope.randomPatientData = function () {

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://randomuser.me/api?nat=ca'
            })
                .then(function successCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    var random = response.data.results[0];

                    $scope.patient.ln = random.name.last;
                    $scope.patient.fn = random.name.first;
                    $scope.patient.bdate = new Date(random.dob);
                    $scope.patient.adr = random.location.street;
                    $scope.patient.city = random.location.city;
                    $scope.patient.postalCode = random.location.postcode;
                    $scope.patient.provState = random.location.state;
                    $scope.patient.country = random.nat;

                    $scope.patient.telHome = random.phone;
                    $scope.patient.telOff = random.phone;
                    $scope.patient.telCel = random.cell;

                    $scope.patient.sex = random.gender === "male" ? "M" : "F";
                    $scope.lang = "FRANCAIS";
                    $scope.email = random.email;

                },
                    function errorCallback(response) {
                        $scope.errorMessage = response.statusText;
                    });

        };

        $scope.createPatient = function () {
            $scope.infoMessagePatient = "";
            $scope.errorMessagePatient = "";

            $scope.patient.etag = $scope.etag.value;

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: baseUrl + 'api/patient',
                data: $scope.patient
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                if (response.data.Success === true)
                    $scope.infoMessagePatient = "Patient Created";
                else if (response.data.Success === false) {
                    $scope.errorMessagePatient = response.data.Message;
                    alert(response.data.Message);
                }

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                $scope.errorMessagePatient = response.statusText;
            });
        };


        $scope.searchPatient = function (s) {
            $scope.response = null;


            var url = baseUrl + 'api/patient?etag=' + $scope.etag.value + '&searchString=' + s;

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url

            }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                $scope.response = response.data;


            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                $scope.errorMessage = response.statusText;
            });
        };

        $scope.test = function() {
            console.log($scope.searchString2);
        };

        $scope.goto = function(path) {
            var url = $scope.appUrl.replace("#", "&et=" + $scope.etag.value + "#");
            $scope.url = url + path;
            $scope.srciFrame = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.url);
        };

        //$scope.gotoRaw = function (url) {
        //    $scope.url = url;
        //    $scope.srciFrame = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
        //};

        $scope.gotoPatient = function(id, type) {
            $scope.gotoUrl({
                etag: $scope.etag.value,
                urlType: type,
                custId: id
            });
        };

        $scope.gotoPage = function(type) {
            $scope.gotoUrl({
                etag: $scope.etag.value,
                urlType: type,
                //lang: "en"
            });
        };

        $scope.gotoUrl = function(data) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: baseUrl + 'api/url',
                data: data
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                $scope.url = response.data.Data;
                $scope.srciFrame = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(response.data.Data);


            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                $scope.errorMessage = response.statusText;
            });
        }

        getEtag();
    }]);
```

Comment: I would need more code from your controller, but why not send the value to your function directly ? ```($event.which === 13)?searchPatient(searchString2):0```

Comment: This looks like the famous `ng-model` needs a dot issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-angularjs-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong

Comment: How do you add controller to html element?

Comment: @JackA. I had it into the $routeProvider : $routeProvider.when('/path/,           { templateUrl: baseUrl + '/Home/Search', controller: 'searchCtrl' });

Comment: @AndrewDonovan it works sending the value directly. But why is the value not sent to the controller?

Comment: @Baral when setting your controller to your route, did you set ```controllerAs```?, because your controller should be named searchController and your controllerAs should be searchCtrl

Comment: I've created a fiddle and tested your code. There is no error. You sure you bind your controller correctly?

Comment: @FatihAktepePlease see my update. I added the way I set the controller

Comment: @AndrewDonovan Please take a look at the way I set the controller

Comment: @Baral Can you post your controller code

Comment: @AndrewDonovan Controller Posted.

Answer (score 0):

I've created fiddle out of your code, but I didn't face any error. Are you sure you bind your controller and app to your HTML correctly? Here is code;

In HTML;

```
<div ng-app=myApp>
    <div ng-controller=myController>

<input id="input1" ng-model="searchString1" />

 <input ng-model="searchString2" ng-keypress="($event.which === 13)?searchPatient():0" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
 <p>
 SearchString1 : {{searchString1}}
 </p>
 SearchString2 :  {{searchString2}}
```

In JS;

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.searchString1 = "";
$scope.searchString2 = "";

$scope.searchPatient = function () {
            $scope.response = null;
            alert($scope.searchString2);

            var url = baseUrl + 'api/patient?etag=' + $scope.etag.value + '&searchString=' + $scope.searchString2;

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url

            }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                $scope.response = response.data;


            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                $scope.errorMessage = response.statusText;
            });
        };
}]);
```

Working fiddle URL; https://jsfiddle.net/z5y03kuk/1/