# $scope var has multiple values that contradict each other?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Okay, this is a strange problem I've never had before and I didn't see anyone else having this problem on the Internet;

For starters, I'm using `AngularJS` and the `$scope` variables.

While using AngularJS i've noticed my variables are showing both the value that was set in the beginning of the controller, for example:

```
$scope.editMode = true;
```

And the value I have set for them in a function inside of the controller, which in that case the function was triggered by a click. For example:

```
$scope.disableEditMode = function() {$scope.editMode = false;}
```

I'm running an interval of a second in the controller to check the variable's value, which is showing me that it is true and then false, and so on...

> Why is it changing by its own? Or why is it having both of the values?
>   What's going on here?

By the way, I'm not sure if that's a reason for this problem, but on the click event which changes the variable value I'm also redirecting the user to another page that uses the same controller, which I thought it might reset that data for the variable but it is clearly not the case.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by _having both values_? it can't possibly be `true` and `false` at the same time.

Comment: @Mackan It shows true and the false and then true and then false and so on in the console

Comment: Can you please add bit more of your code, like the template and the controller? People cannot test it just with that information.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro I can't share the whole controller, it's big and i don't want to reveal some of my code, since it belongs to the company i work in. but what specifically can i provide for you? it's a standard controller with variables and functions, the variable $scope.editMode is set to be true at the beginning and set to be false when the function disableEditMode() is triggered. nothing special really, but i would be happy to share more if needed

Comment: @Mackan this is my interval: 
setInterval(function() {
            console.log($scope.editMode);
        }, 1000);

Comment: So provide a fiddle reproducing this behaviour you are facing, don't need the entire program just the part that causes the problem.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I think you are accidentally calling `disableEditMode()`  on your template.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro even so, how come it shows both true and false, shouldn't it just show false even if that's the case? I will also try to provide more details, but i can't understand what's happening so i will probably not be able to reproduce this bug

Comment: Yes, but it can have more than what I guessed. As I told, we can't be totally sure without the piece of code to reproduce this.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro Is it possible that the controllers were duplicated? so i am actually seeing 2 intervals happening at the same time?

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can log the `$scope.$$id` to see if they are different.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro $scope.$$id is undefined, how do i use it?

Comment: Sorry I meant `$scope.$id` not `$scope.$$id`. My apologies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128063/discussion-between-shay-k-and-lenilson-de-castro).

Comment: @shay.k Try to reproduce the error with a JSFiddle pls

Answer (score 1):

The normal javascript `setInterval()` is not part of Angular's scope.

Angular has it's own implementation, `$interval`, that will evaluate the scope correctly.

```
var timer = $interval(function() {
                console.log($scope.editMode);
            }, 1000);
```

You must include this in the controller though:

```
...controller('myController', function($scope, $interval)..
```

Also, another thing to check/correct is the scope variable if it's in some way in a child controller and used as `ng-model`. 
More here:

- [Why don't the AngularJS docs use a dot in the model directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606936/why-dont-the-angularjs-docs-use-a-dot-in-the-model-directive)
- [If you are not using a .(dot) in your AngularJS models you are doing it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-angularjs-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong)

Comment: Thanks it works, but it's still showing the same thing

Comment: Seems like somehow you've set the value on multiple scopes, or you're running several intervals through different scopes. Hard to say how or why with only the code you've provided. When you track down the error, be sure to check it using $interval though ;)

Comment: I have figured i am actually using duplicated contollers in my project for some reason, so one controller has the correct values and one hasn't. Could i set a variable that will not depend on a controller? i thought of $rootScope but i understand it is not a good practice

Comment: @shay.k Can't you separate the controllers instead? The second link I posted gives a nice example of how scopes can conflict. You can also have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend if you want to use the same scope in two controllers.