# $scope variables are not working inside $scope function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Scope variable returns undefined value when using inside same Scope function.

*index.html*

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
                <form ng-submit="submit()">
                        <span class="input-label">name</span>
                        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name">     
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">                    
                </form>
</body>
```

*app.js*

```
angular.module('starter', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function(){
        alert($scope.name+' scope variable');
            }});
```

*output:*

```
undefined scope variable
```

Comment: pass your ngModel as parameter in submit() of ngSubmit or initialize $scope.name inside controller

Comment: I tested your code , it works fine.http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/13278/

Comment: as @Ved said everything is fine with your code.....but i cant see closing } for your function submit and there is an extra ) in your app.js. this may cause for your problem

Comment: @AnirudhMangalvedhekar Thank you. Passing ngModel works, but initializing $scope.name isn't.

Comment: for scope initialization see ankur's answer...

Comment: just for awareness..It is always better to use dot with models...There is a nice explanation provided http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-angularjs-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong

Comment: @AnirudhMangalvedhekar Thanks for the info. It helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example :

index.php

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
            <form ng-submit="submit()">
                    <span class="input-label">name</span>
                    <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="start.name">     
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">                    
            </form>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.start= {};
     $scope.submit = function(){
       alert($scope.start.name+' scope variable');
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

$scope.name is coming undefined because it is a scope model declared in UI and no value is assigned to it yet. This is expected behavior. If you want some default values assign those from controller or use an `ng-init`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

html files ...

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
                <form ng-submit="submit()">
                        <span class="input-label">name</span>
                        <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name">     
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">                    
                </form>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is your js file

```
angular.module('starter', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.submit = function(){
        alert($scope.name+' scope variable');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just pass the modal value in **ng-submit** like this

1st way ->

```
  <form ng-submit="submit(name)">
      <span class="input-label">name</span>
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name">     
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">                    
   </form>
```

js file

```
   $scope.submit = function(value){
       alert(value+' scope variable');
   }});
```

2nd way ->

or you can do this

```
   <form ng-submit="submit()">
      <span class="input-label">name</span>
      <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name">     
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">                    
   </form>
```

js file

> your code is fine just check parenthesis it is ok code

```
  $scope.submit = function(){
     alert($scope.name+' scope variable');
  };
```

use this working plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/C7oZck4hpt5xHBKkVGku?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

The code looks fine to me there must a syntax error in your controller braces are not completed

I have created a working plunker 
  https://plnkr.co/edit/UGEa1uvS83cJHAcXxYMi?p=preview

```
angular.module('starter', [])
    .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.submit = function() {
            alert($scope.name+' scope variable');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Include the relevant fix and any explanation here, don't just post a link.

Comment: down voter please tell the reason of down vote dont only just down vote

Comment: Good answers should be readable and clearly explained. I fixed the format of your code, but you should highlight your change in some way. If it's the braces that changed, do something like `<---- forgot these` or **bold** them or something.

Comment: OP issue was initialization... What OP really wanted was to have some value showed when submit is clicked without entering any value in input element...So the expected answer would be either initialize the ngModel or pass as parameter to ngSubmit...

Comment: What i have done is angular,there is no need of passing parameter in submit...you are using angular

Comment: in your plunkr please try the following scenario without passing parameter or initializing...

Comment: Which parameter i have not send any parameter

Answer (score -1):

Please go through below code --

**HTML -**

```
 <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <form>
                <span class="input-label">name</span>
                <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="name">     
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="submit();">                    
        </form>
 </body>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    angular.module('starter', []).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name='';
    $scope.submit = function(){
    alert($scope.name+' scope variable');
      };
    });
</script>
```

**Hope it helps you !**