# How to prevent select value to reset on form submit?

Tags: javascript, php

In the view,

```
<select id="gender" ng-model="gender">
     <option value=''>Gender?</option>
     <option value="female" >Female</option>
     <option value="male" >Male</option>
     <option value="other" >Other</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="gender" value="{{gender}}">
```

On submit error, the submitted value is retrived and put as the select value,

```
var theValue = "<?php echo set_value('gender');?>";
var e = document.getElementById("gender");
e.value = theValue;
```

On submitting the incomplete form, the select should retain the post value, and momentarily it does, but resets again. How do I prevent the select to reset and keep the value?

Comment: Use PHP magic methods. It is specially designed for it. sharing sample code in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try to always use an object on your ng-model directives, something like:

```
ng-model="form.gender"
```

This is best described here:
[If you are not using a .(dot) in your AngularJS models you are doing it wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-angularjs-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong)

On the response all you need to do is set the `form.gender` attribute and the two-way-binding of AngularJS will take care of the rest.

Try using the `ng-init` directive to get values from PHP and use them on your AngularJS controller like:

```
ng-init="initGender('<?php echo set_value('gender'); ?>')"
```

and then inside your AngularJS controller:

```
$scope.form = {};
$scope.initGender = function(gender) {
    $scope.form.gender = gender;
};
```

Comment: This one worked out well. 
In the init, instead of calling the function, I put "gender = <?php echo set_value('gender');?>"
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, create this PHP function,

```
    function __selectedDb($ctrlValue,$dbValue)
{
    if($ctrlValue == $dbValue)
        return "selected='selected'";
    else
        return "";
}
```

and use like this,

```
<select class="custom-select" id="selImgTiling" name="selImgTiling" value="<?php echo $arrBgSettings['bg_image_tiling']?>">
                                <option value="no-repeat"   <?php echo __selectedDb('no-repeat',$arrBgSettings['bg_image_tiling'])?>>Tiling Off</option>
                                <option value="repeat"      <?php echo __selectedDb('repeat',$arrBgSettings['bg_image_tiling'])?>> Repeat</option>
                                <option value="repeat-x"    <?php echo __selectedDb('repeat-x',$arrBgSettings['bg_image_tiling'])?>>Repeat Horizontal</option>
                                <option value="repeat-y"    <?php echo __selectedDb('repeat-y',$arrBgSettings['bg_image_tiling'])?>>Repeat Vertical</option>
                            </select>
```

Comment: I think he wants to use PHP with AngularJS though. This is pure PHP.