# Angular: how to save edited values?

Tags: angularjs

here is my plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/0W1SZll1BOK5uuEtdycy?p=preview

im trying to save edited values from my edit contact modal.

here is a edit method that takes current value from object:

```
$scope.edit = function(terminal) {
$scope.name = terminal.name;
$scope.last = terminal.last;
$scope.age = terminal.age;
}
```

i read about angular copy, there is anything else?
any one can help me please ill glat to learn how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a lot of extra manual work by not using one object in `ng-model` in the first place instead of using individual scope properties.

There is a golden rule also that [if you don't have a dot in ng-model you are doing it wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-angularjs-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong)

Do something like:

```
<input ng-model="terminal.name">
<input ng-model="terminal.age">
```

Then work along the following lines:

```
$scope.edit = function(terminal) {
    // store reference to terminal being edited
    $scope.currentTerminal = terminal;
    // make a copy so live one is not affected -- will be used in form
    $scope.terminal = angular.copy(terminal);
}

$scope.save = function(){
  // update stored original with changes
  angular.extend($scope.currentTerminal,  $scope.terminal);
  // reset terminal used in form
  $scope.terminal ={};
}
```

I would strongly suggest you get rid of jQuery and bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootstrap insted

Comment: thank you charlietfl, have a question: im saving the data to an database with php, i need new function to save the editing values to? or the extend method do that automaticly?

Comment: all the more reason to use one object...very simple to stick it into a `$http` and only update the view version on success

Comment: hi charlietfl, tried to do ngmodel with dot like u sed, but then when i click the edit button and after that the add button, there is values on the add form input

Answer (score 2):

Use angular.copy when assigning value of object or array to another variable and that object value should not be changed.

Without deep copy or using angular.copy, changing value of property or adding any new property update all object referencing that same object. Your JS will look like this:

```
$scope.edit = function(terminal) {
    $scope.name = angular.copy(terminal.name);
    $scope.last = angular.copy(terminal.last);
    $scope.age = angular.copy(terminal.age);
    }
```

Comment: thank you hamza, have a question: im saving the data to an database with php, i need new function to save the editing values to? or the copy method do that automaticly?

Comment: Put those values in some extra javascript variables using same angular.copy, not in some extra $scope variable since, $scope tell us what values are going to get bind with our view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the index of the row that you are going to edit. pass the index when you click on edit button.

Change in script.js

```
$scope.edit = function(terminal,index) {

    $scope.name = terminal.name;
    $scope.last = terminal.last;
    $scope.age = terminal.age;
    $scope.edit_index = index

 }


$scope.saveEdit =function(){
    index = $scope.edit_index
    $scope.terminals[index].name = $scope.name;

  }
```

Change in index.html

```
<td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModalLong" ng-click="edit(terminal,$index)">Edit</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="saveEdit()">Save</button>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/GpVB2dUiHCY6NslQDuBe?p=preview