# Filtering on some JSON value with AngularJS filter

Tags: html, angularjs, filter

I need to add a free text filter with only one text input to a table.
Unfortunately standard filter operates on all values. For examples with this JSON array:

```
myJsonArray = [{col1: "xxx", col2: "yyy", col3: "zzz"},{...}]
```

I want to filter only on col1 and col2.
Here's my code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search for the first 2 columns..." ng-model="searchCols">
[...]
<tr ng-repeat="a in myJsonArray | filter : searchCols">
[...]
```

How can I say to filter: filter only col1 and col2 with text in searchCols?
I've already tried something like this but didn't work:

```
<tr ng-repeat="a in myJsonArray | filter : {'col1' :searchCols, 'col2': searchCols">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right tracks, check this snippet:

```js
angular.module("app", [])

  .controller('TestController', function() {
    this.list = [{
      name: 'John',
      email: 'john@a.com',
    }, {
      name: 'Mark',
      email: 'mark@a.com',
    }, ];

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestController as ctrl">
  Search: <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.searchTerm" />
<hr/>
  <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.list | filter: {name: ctrl.searchTerm}">
    <b>{{item.name}}</b> ({{item.email}})
  </div>
</div>
```

If this does not work on your environment, you may have issues regarding [the dot on the ngModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-angularjs-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong)

You can combine multiple conditions by adding properties to the filter object, for example:

`| filter: {name: ctrl.searchTerm, email: ctrl.searchTerm}`

Will require the `name` **and** `email` to be equal to the search term.

If you need to do an OR condition instead, apparently you've to write a custom function:

```js
angular.module("app", [])

  .controller('TestController', function() {
    this.searchTerm = "";
    this.list = [{
      name: 'John',
      email: 'john@a.com',
      team: 'Team A'
    }, {
      name: 'Mark',
      email: 'mark@a.com',
      team: 'Team B'
    }];
    var that = this;
    this.filterResults = function(item) {
      var searchTerm = that.searchTerm.toLowerCase();
      return !that.searchTerm ||
        ((item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(that.searchTerm) != -1) ||
          (item.team.toLowerCase().indexOf(that.searchTerm) != -1));
    };

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestController as ctrl">
  Search: <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.searchTerm" />
  <hr/>
  <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.list | filter:ctrl.filterResults">
    <b>{{item.name}}</b> ({{item.email}})
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, this work with one column. But if in your JSON there are 3 columns, how is syntax for concatenate more than one columns in the ng-repeat filter? For examples you have name, email and address but you want to filter only name and email...

Comment: `| filter: {name: ctrl.searchTerm, email: ctrl.searchTerm}` should work

Comment: With this syntax no errors but filter work only with the first parameter: name. Email field is ignored