# Why ng-change is not working in chosen js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'M using `chosen` dropdown in `angularJS`. In chosen DD `ng-change` is not working.

```
<div ng-controller="nSumInstalController">

<div>
    <select style="width:240px;" ng-model="circle" ng-change ="circleChange(circle)" ng-options="report.Circles for report in reportsValuesOptions track by report.id" chosen></select>
</div>
```

and Controller is

```
    $scope.reportsValuesOptions =
```

```js
[{
    "Circles": "All",
    "id": 0
  },
  {
    "Circles": "Balasore Circle",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "Circles": "Baripada Circle",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "Circles": "Bhadrak Circle",
    "id": 3
  },
  {
    "Circles": "Jajpur Road Circle",
    "id": 4
  },
  {
    "Circles": "Keonjhar Circle",
    "id": 5
  }
]
```

```
 $scope.circleChange = function (circle) {
     alert();
 })
```

and used Links:

> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chosen-localytics/1.4.0/angular-chosen.min.js
>   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.6.2/chosen.min.css

I don't know why it's not working and what i made wrong? Please help me this issue. I'm trying since 3 days.

**Update:** I'M using `ng-include` will it cause any issue?

Comment: You have space between `ng-change` and `="circleChange(circle)"` but I'm not sure whether chosen works with `ng-change`. You could change your model to [use dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-angularjs-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong) and [watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) changes on that value in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Hope I have understood your problem correctly.
I feel that you dont have to write chose seperately.

```
<div ng-controller="nSumInstalController">
<div>
<select style="width:240px;" ng-model="circle" ng-change ="circleChange(circle)" ng-options="report.Circles for report in reportsValuesOptions track by report.id"></select>
</div>
```

The above should work fine.

Else try adding id and name attributes, like this:

```
<div ng-controller="nSumInstalController">
<div>
<select style="width:240px;" id="chosen" name="chosen" ng-model="circle" ng-change ="circleChange(circle)" ng-options="report.Circles for report in reportsValuesOptions track by report.id"></select>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you.