# Accessing the checkbox checked from the controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

There are a couple of checkboxes and a button. When i press the button need to know which all checkboxes are selected in the controller.

I have a controller
Mcontroller
where i have `$scope.selected_machines = {}`

html file have the checkboxes created dynamically

```
<tr ng-repeat="(m, res) in results.byMachine">
   <td> {{ m }}
     <input type="checkbox" id ="{{ m }}" name="bypass_check"
            ng-disabled="disableBypassWaitForDrainedCheck(m, results.bypassed_machines)"
            ng-model="selected_machines[m]">
  </td>
```

the html file is called using a directive

```
.directive('visualizer', [$window, function ($window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        selected: '<selected',
      },
      templateUrl: 'static/html/ng/visualizer.html',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.data = {}
        scope.pollers = {}
        scope.rendered = {}
        scope.table = {}
.........
```

The buttons click function is `bypassWaitForDrained()` function called from an angular service file and is defined in the controller `Mcontroller`. 
I need to access the checked checkboxes from this function. Tried following and the value in selected_machines are never updated. Basically the `ngModel` `selected_machines` data is not getting updated in the controller. May i know what could be the reason ?

```
$scope.bypassWaitForDrained = function(pipelineId) {

    Loop through selected_machines
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-angularjs-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong

Comment: try with adding extra dot in model scope, so try to replace `selected_machines` to parhaps something like `checkboxes.selected`.
this is because selected_machines will attach to child scope build by ng-repeat

Comment: @PraveenSoni The ng-model binds to a property of an object, `selected_machines[m]`. It  uses bracket notation instead of dot notation. That is sufficient to avoid the data hiding problem.

Answer (score 0):

The directive is using isolated scope, that means its scope does not inherit anything from parent scope. Parent scope properties need to be bound to the isolate scope:

```
.directive('visualizer', [$window, function ($window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        selected: '<selected',
        //IMPORTANT
        selected_machines: '<selectedMachines'
      },
      templateUrl: 'static/html/ng/visualizer.html',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.data = {}
        scope.pollers = {}
        scope.rendered = {}
        scope.table = {}
```

### Usage:

```
<div ng-controller="Mcontroller">
    <visualizer selected-machines="selected_machines" selected="...">
    </visualizer>
</div>
```

This will bind the `$scope.selected_machines` object reference in the `Mcontroller` to the isolated scope of the directive.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Isolating the scope of a directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive)