# angularjs: how to access to get data results. getting undefined right now

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am working on loading data from (entity framework/sql view) to a drop-down menu in my app front end.

I am able to call the server side method and successfully verify that the results contain the data that I need.

I am making a mistake in how I am accessing the elements of the data array, that I intend to use to populate the drop-down menu. After I complete the execution, the drop-down menu displays "unidefined" 37 times, which is the number of records the GET returns.

Here is what I see in Chrome developer tools:

[image: chrome developer tools screen shot]

As you can see, I assign the data.data to my $scope.MeetingListarray.

in the html view I attempt to use the contents of $scope.MeetingListas follows:

```
            <div>
                <select ng-model="selectedMeeting">
                    <option value="">--Select Meetings--</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="meeting in MeetingList" value="{{meeting.MeetingID}}">{{meeting.MeetingName}}</option>                      
                </select>
            </div>
```

AngularJS

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', function ($scope, $http, $window) {

    $scope.selectedMeeting = null;
    $scope.MeetingList = [];

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/VirtualMeetings/CrossReference/Home/GetMeetingList',
        data: {}
    }).then(function (data) {
        $scope.MeetingList = data;
    });
```

What am I doing incorrectly when populating the array and using it in the html view?
Could someone please show me mi error, and the right way of coding this?

Greatly appreciated it.

Thank you.

Updated Screen-Shot

[image: second screen shot - chrome dev tools]

This worked for me, in order to populate the drop down menu/list

html view:

```
                <select ng-model="model.selectedMeeting">                        
                    <option ng-repeat="meeting in MeetingList" value="{{meeting.MeetingID}}">{{meeting.MeetingTitle}}</option> 
                    <option value="">--Select Meeting--</option>                     
                </select>
```

angularjs

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/VirtualMeetings/CrossReference/Home/GetMeetingList',
    data: {}
}).then(function (res) {
    $scope.MeetingList = res.data.data;
});
```

I needed to add one more data in the assignment of array.

Answer (score 0):

The `then()` of `$http` returns a response object that has a `data` property where you see the actual server sent data.

Try:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/VirtualMeetings/CrossReference/Home/GetMeetingList',
    data: {}
}).then(function (res) {
    $scope.MeetingList = res.data;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Let me make that change and see if it works. Brb.

Comment: One other issue I see in your code is there should always be an object in `ng-model`. You can run into child scope issues when you don't have one. Golden rule...always have a dot in `ng-model`. Using `controller as` insted of `$scope syntax helps resolve such issues but if must use `$scope` create objects in controller instead of primitives

Comment: I made the suggested change. Still nothing on the drop down. I uploaded a screen shot for you to see what I see in the dev tools. Again, thank you.

Comment: Also better to use `ng-options` for a `<select>`

Comment: I do not understand what is the meaning of "always have a dot in ng-model" - like: selected.Meeting?

Comment: In controller `$scope.model={selectedMeeting :null}` and in html `ng-model="model.selectedMeeting"`. Also makes it easier later when you need to submit something through `$http` send the whole model object and no need to build a new one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128323/if-you-are-not-using-a-dot-in-your-angularjs-models-you-are-doing-it-wrong

Comment: made changes, but still no data in drop-down menu

Comment: did you switch to ng-options?

Comment: not that one, how is that supposed to look like? I need to be able to have the meetingid as the value, and the meeting name as the displayed text. I don't think I understand how that works with ng-options.

Comment: Need to look at docs. It's been quite a few years since I used angularjs. Will find lots of other questions here about it though also. Probably some I even answered years ago

Comment: I’ll keep trying. Thank you for your help charlietfl

Comment: using ng-options or ng-repeat?

Comment: ng-repeat. the issue was with the results assignment. I needed to add one more data: res.data.data. That worked. I left the html for the ddl untouched with the exemption of making a change to the way I declare the model for select. I posted and update in the original post. Thank you for your help charlietfl.

Comment: Ohhh i missed that in the image that you send another property named data also in your object from server...sorry i missed that

Comment: I had a feeling that the problem resided in something that was right in front of us. I just keep editing that part and finally it worked.