# ng-keyup firing but not reading properly when used with an ng-if inside a directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-if

I have a directive and it works fine in a way such that when I type something the `search()` scope function inside my directive fires and sets `$scope.query` with the input text.

here is the directive template

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="system-filter-header">
        <div class="no-gutter">
            <div class="system-search-wrapper search-wrapper-width">
                <i ng-click="search($evt)" class="fa fa-search"></i>
                <input type="text" ng-keyup=search($evt)  class="search pull-left suggesstions-styles"
                ng-model="query" ng-attr-placeholder="Search...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

here is the scope function which gets triggered

```js
$scope.search = function() {
          console.log($scope.query.length)
}
```

**But** when I used an `ng-if="true"` in first line of template (`true` used for generalizing only, I want to do a different conditional check inside `ng-if`)  such that,

```html
<div class="container" ng-if="true">
```

still the `search` gets triggered but the `console.log` gives always 0 and it doesn't seem to update the `$scope.query` value as it stays as `$scope.query = ''`
throughout the typing.

**EDIT**
Here is a an [example codepen](https://codepen.io/cmgchess/pen/vYWXgYY) with almost similar behaviour. The problem is with the `searchBox` directive and I have added `ng-if=true` to the template but searching doesn't work. When I remove the `ng-if` searching works fine.

Any reason for this?

Comment: Can you post a little more of the code from your directive's controller or link function?  That might help us to better help you debug. Thanks!  :  )

Comment: @GeraldLeRoy hello my directive controller has `$scope.query = ''` initialized and then there is this function `$scope.search` which manipulates the value of query. it was working as expected until i put the ng-if

Comment: @GeraldLeRoy hi I added a demo link as well

Comment: As an addendum to my answer, I strongly recommend you get off AngularJS 1.0.x. Even if an upgrade to Angular2+ isn't feasible, you should do what you can to get to 1.8

Comment: @JacobStamm im working on an old long running project which uses 1.4 so I dont have a choice :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of thumb in AngularJS: [your `ng-model` should always include a dot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18128502/4028303). Otherwise AngularJS directives that create child scopes (like `ng-if` or `ng-repeat`) will create a duplicate property on that child scope instead of the parent scope. Following the [controllerAs convention](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers) completely mitigates this behavior.

Comment: hi thanks for answering. does this mean `$scope.query = ''` should be something like `$scope.query = {value: ''}` and have `ngModel` as `query.value`

Comment: or is there a workaround with `$scope.query=''`

Comment: @cmgchess yes, `ng-model="query.value"` will do the trick

Comment: it seems to work in the demo link. I will confirm after testing with actual project